# How to make .NET code which is included in my unity game to run on android?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a helicopter game which run by some readings come from an external imu sensor which connected by bluetooth module hc-05 and an UNO arduino.
Right now the game is working well on my laptop by using a .NET code to receive the data from the arduino.
Now I need to make the game to run on my android mobile, what should I do with the .Net code to be able to run on the mobile, or is there another way to do that without using .NET code?

This is the .NET code used in the game.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;
using InTheHand.Net;
using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace bluetooth_code_from_stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        // My BT USB adapter
        private static BluetoothEndPoint EP = new BluetoothEndPoint(BluetoothAddress.Parse("30:D1:6B:F2:5F:40"), BluetoothService.BluetoothBase);
        private static BluetoothClient BC = new BluetoothClient(EP);

        // The BT device that would connect
        private static BluetoothDeviceInfo BTDevice = new BluetoothDeviceInfo(BluetoothAddress.Parse("98:D3:B1:FD:87:94"));

        private static NetworkStream stream = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(BTDevice.DeviceAddress, "1234"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PairRequest: OK");

                if (BTDevice.Authenticated)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Authenticated: OK");

                    BC.SetPin("1234");

                    BC.BeginConnect(BTDevice.DeviceAddress, BluetoothService.SerialPort, new AsyncCallback(Connect), BTDevice);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Authenticated: No");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PairRequest: No");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Connect(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            if (result.IsCompleted)
            {
                // client is connected now :)
                Console.WriteLine(BC.Connected);
                stream = BC.GetStream();

                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        byte[] received = new byte[1024];
                        stream.Read(received, 0, received.Length);
                        Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received));                        
                    }
                    catch (IOException exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Client has disconnected!!");
                        break;
                    }
                }                
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is that you can't (at least not as-is).
You may want to look into Xamarin (I suppose Unity might work as well). You can't run this .NET desktop program natively on Android.
Instead, you'll need to use a framework like the aforementioned to generate an executable from the C# that is compiled to a runtime for Android.

This means you'll need to refactor your code, and likely find native equivalents for the BT libraries you're using from nuget.

Honestly, you'll most likely end up with almost entirely new code, so you wouldn't really be using this exact program, but it's generally possible to use C#/.NET to do what you want to do, just not the way you want to.

Comment: Does xamarin provide some functionalities to connect the game with an external device via bluetooth?